# how to add certain number of blank lines into multiline textbox in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Normally, a multi-line textbox does not contain any lines.
But I want to add a certain number of blank lines to the text box.
I have no idea how I can do this.

Comment: `For i = 0 to 9 : TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine) : Next` or `TextBox1.AppendText(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 10)))` or `TextBox1.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, New String(9) {}))`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Lines` property of a `TextBox` is an array containing the lines of text. Just assign to it a `String` array of the appropriate length:

```vb
TextBox1.Lines = New String(lineCount - 1) {}
```

I haven't tested but I wouldn't expect that you would even have to set the elements, i.e. an array full of `Nothing` will do the job.

Comment: It works because the setter of the property (TextBoxBase) only considers the lines count, then initializes a StringBuilder and appends `\r\n` N times (plus the value, if any).